# Multiple filters in Rows.Find()

Tags: vb.net, filter

I have a code where I am trying to delete records by pulling records from database and then updating them with Delete Flag set to "Y". I am facing issues in discarding the previously deleted items to come up in my search.

This is what I am using to get the table rows -

```
Datatableadapter.getData().Rows.Find(ID.Text)
```

This searches on the Primary field of the table automatically. Now i want to add delete flag filter also to the search criteria. Pls suggest what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Find` is meant when searching by the entity key or composite key. Use the `Where` to search by additional criteria. You can either use both conditions in your where, or use Find so you leverage the clustered index (ideally), and then where to enforce your business rule that the element has not been deleted.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for the reply. I am not able to locate how to use this Where clause as it is not coming as an option with 'Rows' like i had 'Find'. Can you pls share a snippet of how to use it?

Comment: Please make sure you have imported System.Linq so that the Where extension method is available on your object. This JSFiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/Le1fX3) shows a basic where with Linq to Objects.  Once you include the Linq namespace, `Datatableadapter.getData().Rows.Find(ID.Text).Where(Function(r) r.IsDeleted = False)` should be something similar to what you need.